# NSLog shows the error "expression result unused" and not working. iphone?

Tags: iphone, nslog

i am simply trying to NSLog something on xcode and it gives the error "Expression result unused" , i cant print anything using NSLog. actually i changed the Build configuration in edit scheme to Debug. i dont know what is actually the error?

need some help

Comment: Please show your actual code... There is no way to actually know how to advise you without it in this case.

Comment: This occurs when you have an expression and don't either assign it to a variable or use it in a function. Perhaps you are closing out the call to NSLog and passing your arguments in the next statement: `NSLog(@"%g"); i;`... but it's hard to say before seeing the code.

Comment: but the error came for a simple nslo also. NSLog(@"this also gives error");

Comment: Try cmd+clicking NSLog and check what the definition of it is. You may have a framework that redefines it as something you don't mean to use it as.

Comment: yes i checked the definition and it shows    #define kFeedback_URL_preference @"Feedback_URL_preference"
#define LOGGING_ON NO
#define NSLog
#import "UIUtility.h",

Answer (score 2):

I had similar status.
My reason was next code.
#define NSLog
Please check there is any redefinition of NSLog.

Comment: got rid of the warning by writing `#define NSLog(...)   //`